# Tahor and Tamei

Tags: words, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

Tahor and Tamei are often translated as clean and unclean or (ritually) pure and impure.

*But what exactly do they mean, what are the definitions for tahor and tamei? How does one render "ritually" pure or impure?*

(Is Tahor something like sanctification by elevating? And Tamei a lower status of some kind? And hence, if we strip the words “pure” and “impure” of their physical connotations, and perceive a more spiritual meaning, could they signify the presence or absence of holiness?)

Please help me out to get to the clear and pure essence of these words :)

Comment: [one answer](/a/7535)

Comment: They are technical terms denoting specific legal statuses. I don't know what else you are looking for. That's what they mean.

Comment: Well clean and unclean could mean something like cleared and dirty, but thats not their meaning in Hebrew, pure and impure could mean something like not mixed and something mixed with anything else, but these also don't capture the essence of Tahor and Tamei... hopefully this helps. I want to know what these words capture in their meaning.

Comment: The problem is that the words in Hebrew do not translate to existing terms in English. The terms need to be explained in their own context. An analogy could be made to the fact that the English word *angel* gives the wrong connotation to the word *malach*

Comment: So there is no concept for Tahor and Tamei; a common factor between all the contexts? I'm not looking for a word to translate both, but more a description of some kind.

Comment: Even regular English words do not retain consistent meanings independent of context. "Hot" can be something physically warm, electrified, popular, stolen, etc. If it's not that why in "pure" English, why would you expect commonality within a translation?

Answer (score 3):

There is quite a simple way to define purity and impurity as they are denoted in the Torah. Purity is everything that is connected to Life, hope, possibility and growth. Impurity, or Tameh - stems from the word 'Satum' which means closed off, and connotes anything that is disconnected from its life source, with no possibility for connection, growth or movement. So everything that is connected with death, is in the realm of impurity. These terms have nothing to do with physical cleanliness or dirt.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Rachel!  Nice answer +1.  Do you by chance have an earlier source that mentions this? If you do, you can [edit] it into your answer, which would give it more credibility.

Answer (score 0):

Tameh implies something that is close to hephsed (debilitation).

Tahor implies something that is wholesome within itself.

So that a dead person, which is the greatest hephsed, has the most tumah, for example.

Comment: Interesting approach. Any source?

Answer (score 0):

I heard a Rabbi that said that it was the status of the person. Ritually impure or ritually pure.  It did not mean dirty or clean.  He said that a tame person still has to observe Shabbat, eat kosher, etc. although it is ritually impure. Hope this helps, it help me understand better.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Michael and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!